# How can I automatically add child pages to pages in a WP menu?

Tags: pages, menus, automation, children

In the WP menu creation GUI there's the `Automatically add top level pages` option. I would like to do the opposite, for any page that is in the menu, automatically add it's child pages. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: no.

If you want dynamic updating of your menu items, you would probably be better-served using `wp_list_pages()` or `wp_page_menu()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought maybe there would be a way to hook into the menu to expand the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, at least, is to use this plugin: [Auto Submenu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-submenu/)

> WordPress can only automatically add new top-level pages to menus.
>   With Auto Submenu, new child pages will also be automatically added to
>   menus.